# Shapes around certain text in textview

Tags: android, html, formatting, textview, nine-patch

In the screen shot below there are squares around the numbers and circles around superscript text.

I have found plenty of sites that puts background shapes in the 
`TextView` both not around a certain word in the text and some sites that discuss 
nine-patch.

Is this possible to do in the `TextView` or do i need to use a different `View`? Any help with this would be fantastic.

Thank-you

[image: screen shot is here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be a `WebView` with content formatted as HTML.

Comment: Thank-you for the suggestion. Changed to WebView in my app and things started to fall into place

Answer (score 0):

You can design an HTML string for your texts and render it in TextView using

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("htmlcontent"));`

or you can load HTML string content in WebView using

```
webview.loadData("htmlcontent", "text/html", "utf-8");
```

or if you have html file, you can directly load it in WebView using
    webView.loadUrl(url);

PS : List of HTML tags supported by TextView http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Answer (score 0):

There is some formatting you can do on a text view, I'm not sure about boxes but you can check it out:

Spanned http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html and it's subclasses
and in Html there's a fromHtml that returns a SpannableString http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

maybe on those classes, find your answer, you will.